# CREATE PDF FROM GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

function createBulkPDFs(){

const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("id");

const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");

const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");

const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,15).getDisplayValues();

let errors = [];

data.forEach(row => {

```
try{

 createpdf(row[0],row[1],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[0] + " " + row[1],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
 errors.push("");
} catch(err){
 errors.push("Failed");
}
```

}); //close forEach

currentSheet.getRange(2,15,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(errors);

}

function
createpdf(First_name,Last_name,Description,Address,Location,Date_of_letter,Date_of_Def,pdfname,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {

const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);

const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());

const body = tempDocFile.getBody();

body.replaceText("{First name}",First_name);

body.replaceText("{Last name}",Last_name);

body.replaceText("{Description}",Description);

body.replaceText("{Address}",Address);

body.replaceText("{Location}",Location);

body.replaceText("{Date of letter}",Date_of_letter);

body.replaceText("{Date of Def}",Date_of_Def);

tempDocFile.saveAndClose();

const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MineType.Pdf);

pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName("pdfname");

Comment: Please attach the code, sample doc and sheet.

Comment: let errors = [];
  data.forEach(row => {
    try{
     createpdf(row[0],row[1],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[0] + " " + row[1],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
     errors.push("");
    } catch(err){
     errors.push("Failed");
    }
  }); //close forEach
  currentSheet.getRange(2,15,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(errors);

Comment: instead of using these codes which are actually not working but i want to use loop for multiple columns more than 20 and loop for every rows.

Comment: Kindly edit your post and attach the code along with the sample data from Sheets.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: these are the codes i am trying to run but i am not able to create multiple pdf based on my excel data. what changes can be made to these codes or anything with loop or i want to add more fields to it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code and found some issues.

- The use of `setValues()` when populating rows of data. The data should be in 2 dimensional. Each sub-array represents row of data.
- The value used in getAs() should be `application/pdf` instead of `MineType.pdf`.

**Here is my sample data:**

[image: sample data]

**Code:**

```
function createBulkPDFs() {
    const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("id");
    const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");
    const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");
    const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    const data = currentSheet.getRange(1, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow(), 11).getDisplayValues();
    let errors = [];
    data.forEach(row => {
        try {
            createpdf(row[0], row[1], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[0] + " " + row[1], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
            errors.push("Success");
        } catch (err) {
            errors.push("Failed");
        }
    }); //close forEach
    let newArr = [];
    while(errors.length > 0) {
        newArr.push(errors.splice(0,1));
    }
    currentSheet.getRange(1, 12, currentSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(newArr);
}


function createpdf(First_name, Last_name, Description, Address, Location, Date_of_letter, Date_of_Def, pdfname, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder){
    const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
    const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
    const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
    body.replaceText("{First name}", First_name);
    body.replaceText("{Last name}", Last_name);
    body.replaceText("{Description}", Description);
    body.replaceText("{Address}", Address);
    body.replaceText("{Location}", Location);
    body.replaceText("{Date of letter}", Date_of_letter);
    body.replaceText("{Date of Def}", Date_of_Def);
    tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
    const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs('application/pdf');
    pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfname);
}
```

**PDF:**

[image: PDFS]

**Sheets:**

[image: sheets]

**References:**

- [getAs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getascontenttype)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: i am still getting error and last column it is showing failed.

Comment: @VidhiSakhidas - What is the error message?

Comment: @ Nikko J. code are executed properly but in last column it is showing failed so pdf are not getting generated and temp files values are not getting replaced.

Comment: Have you tried removing the try catch to locate the source of error?

Comment: and temp files values are not getting replaced.in doc file values are not getting replaced. do we need to set that these are row heading or something like that

Comment: Execution log
11:51:58 PM Notice Execution started
11:52:00 PM Error 
Exception: You do not have permission to call DocumentApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
createPDF @ Untitled.gs:24
(anonymous) @ Untitled.gs:10
createBulkPDFs @ Untitled.gs:8

Comment: The issue is on the authorization scopes of your project. It seems that the editor didn't catch the DocumentApp scope during your first run. I would suggest you to create a new spreadsheet, paste the data and code, rerun the script and, authorize the app to access your data.

Comment: still having the issue if copied in new sheet.

Comment: @VidhiSakhidas - try this: [Google Apps Script: Setting explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)

Comment: J, please comment what to be done on this

Comment: I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it.